# Resource Tagging on EC2 instance, getting an error "Key not found in Tags properties" while creating stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

```
Resources:
  EC2Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: rwdex-nonprod-dev-ecp-host1
      - Key: Application
        Value: rwdex
      - key: Consumer
        Value: rwdex-nonprod-admi
      - Key: Costcenter
        Value: 10005883  
      - Key: Division
        Value: MRL
      - Key: Environment
        Value: Development
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple!
Many parts of CloudFormation templates are CASE-SENSITIVE.
For your 3rd Tag (specifically, "key: Consumer" )..
       .. the LHS is ALL lower-case 'key'!
Fix the LHS to 'Title-Case' .. as in 'Key' (capital K).

Answer (score 1):

Correct format is as below

```
Tags:
  -
    Key: Name
    Value: rwdex-nonprod-dev-ecp-host1
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-ec2.html#scenario-ec2-instance